# Data remove from variable when reload the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I am working in laravel and angular js. In laravel I have used event broadcast and use pusher notification. And in angular side I have subscribe channel and receive that notification.

Now, I have store pusher data into one variable and display it into html. But, when I reload page than notification is removed.

Angular js :

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('Pusher-key', {
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('ticket-'+$login_user_id);
channel.bind('ticket-notification', function(data) {
    var i = $scope.notification.length;
    $scope.notification[i] = {"id":data.ticket.id,"subject":data.ticket.subject};
    $scope.total_notification = $scope.notification.length;
    console.log($scope.total_notification);
});

this.update_notification = function(notification_id,index) {
    $scope.notification.splice(index,1);
    $scope.total_notification = $scope.notification.length;
}
```

Now, I want to store **notification** variable globally.So when I reload page than it can not affect on that variable and also can display in another browser.

So what should I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the variable in the local storage of the browser. So it won't get deleted on refresh. But you won't be able to get that from another browser, as all browsers maintain their own copy of local storage based on the domain. If this is the case, you will have to develop some mechanism to get the notifications from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage would be perfect.
Set the pusher data into localStorage. Now, whenever you are reloading the page get the stored data from localStorage.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) you could find more about localStorage.

Comment: I can not use it in another browser

Comment: I guess "another browser" means new window of same browser. Because passing data from say Chrome to Firefox is not possible without server.

Comment: It is possible to use PouchDB : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pouchdb/pouchdb_read_document.htm

It is good for it or not? Cz i don't have any idea about it.